# Refresh UserForm without refreshing worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

While working with Excel, I have many times faced the problem with Screen Refreshing.

Most of the time, in order to speed up VBA, programmers will use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`. This will temporarily (until cancelled) stop screen refreshing. Unfortunately, there are cases, such as implementing progress bar, when you actually **want** to show some progress to the user. The problem is that the already mentioned command has stopped all screen refreshing.

This means, that even if on your `UserForm` you call a command to change a label (e.g. which would state *Processing transaction 15 of 250*) but you simply cannot get it to display.

What some people do in this case, is to temporarily enable `ScreenUpdating`, and right away disable it. This procedure is unfortunately unreliable, as if you have some difficult procedure (inserting complex formulas into cells) you are not guaranteed all the time that it will also refresh the label itself. Also the problem with this approach is, that you repaint not only your desired `UserForm`, but also `Worksheet` as well, and therefore this 'refresh' slows down your code quite a bit.

How can you refresh `UserForm` without refreshing the **whole Excel**?

Comment: Use the `Application.StatusBar` instead - that's what it's there for.

Comment: Application.StatusBar is indeed viable solution, however this post is talking about `UserForms` and showing progress there

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple.

Let's say that your userform is named `frm_Main`, so then in your VBA code you can simply call `frm_Main.Repaint`.

Simple as that!

Comment: in some cases a `Doevents`is better than `Form.Repaint` , you have to try, depending on the job to do. Also, you can refresh only a part of the userform, simply by puting what's to be refreshed in a Frame and then `Frame1.Repaint`.

Comment: indeed that's right, I cannot argue with that. Also +1 for specifying frame.Repaint...that's actually even faster than repainting whole userform