How can I prevent my Excel VBA forms from distorting when the user scrolls down using the vertical scroll bar?
I have created forms in Excel (2402) using VBA. Due to their size, I have included a vertical scroll bar so that the user can scroll down to see all the information.
However, when the user scrolls down, the form interface often distorts or collapses. How can I fix this issue and ensure that the form remains intact when the user scrolls down?
I don't know how can I fix this problem.
Sorry for my delay response. Here it is an example of the excel tool:
form_example.xlsm
When I scroll down the opened form, it distorts.
distorted_form
Thanks in advance!!

Please provide exact directions for how to reproduce.

Please provide a minimal, reproducible example, including the relevant code

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Try repainting the form as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37242364/refresh-userform-without-refreshing-worksheet

Hello @MacroMarc !! I have tried using:
Sub OpenUserForm()
UserForm1.Show
UserForm1.Repaint

End Sub
However, the problem still persist

I have tried to force the repaint whenever the mouse has been moved:
Private Sub UserForm_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Me.Repaint
End Sub

However, I don't know if this is the best approach.
